# moving multiple indexes using the pop function in python

Tags: python

How can I use the pop function in a loop to pop from a certain index to a certain index. I need to move the front end of a list to the end and then delete a specific index. Here is my code so far. The idea is to cycle through a list [1,2,3,4,5,6,7....] up until the inputted number. Then it is supposed to delete the inputted number that is the count. The issue arises when needing to move multiple items to the back of the list in the count using the pop function. This code runs for example using the input 7 as the list and 2 as the count,but not 7 as the list and 3 as the count because it can't move more than one index to the back of the list.

```
def counter(L,m) 
    for i in range(m):
        if len(L) >= m:
            del L[m-1]
            L.append(L.pop(0))
            print("removed this number")
            return L
        else:
            if len(L) < m:
                del L[m]
```

Comment: You should have a look at [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) - smart container, implements [rotation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate) just for you.

Comment: from the code it is not reproducable what is the input and desired output here, maybe write this up as a function?!

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused. Your last line should cause an index error. 
Are you trying to shorten a list to a specific index?
It sounds like you should use slices, though I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do.

```
truncated = L[m:]
L = L[:m]
for i in truncated:
    print("removed this number") #probably want to use interpolation here as well
```

to move the front to the back use [::-1]